# ajax file loading with css and loading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Hi i am looking for more help with my ajax

i am trying to load pages into my mobile site under the menu witch i can do perfectly fine but it wouldnt load the css file properly that i have tried to fix by appending the css in headers

and then i wanted it to show a loading image wile the ajax request was working witch i done perfectly fine and had it showing

and then i wanted to put it all under one function and now i am having problems i cant get all the code to work together

here is the code i have so far in my function please note i am no good with it i just refrance and go from what i read and learn i am learning now

```
    function login(){ 
    $.ajax({
    var pagelink = "";
    var url = pagelink + "login.php";
    var cssLink = pagelink + $(this).attr('href');

url : url,
type : "GET",
dataType : "html",
beforeSend: function(){
    $('#loading').show();
},
complete: function(){
    $('#loading').hide();
},
success: function(data){
   $("#demo").html(data);
   $("#demo link").each(function() {
   $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='" + cssLink + "' />")
    });
}.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $("#demo").html("Error!! File is not loaded");
       });
    });

 }
```

any help on getting this to work under the one function would be great

or maybe a way to have the loading image work for every function on my page

Comment: You should not load CSS via AJAX, Add your CSS in pageload only

Comment: i have to load the css via ajax as there are conflicting eliments on the pages i want to load so i need the css file changed everytime the page is changed to make sure the conflicts never happen i read about and found the append as the only way to work around this

as you may know wen you use .load or get ajax dosent all ways load the css file from the page you want to load and it becomes a problem as all my buttons and stuff lose the style

Comment: Appending/removing isn't the only option. `<link onload="Loaded()" rel="stylesheet" disabled href="...">` & `document.styleSheets[0].disabled = true|false`

Comment: the page dosent reload the page stays static but a div on the page is filled with the contents of a loaded file using ajax and said loaded file has its own css

but again none of the replys are actually helping here so am looking for someone who knows ajax and javascript that can help me put everything i have in a working function